# visual studio 2015 community edition

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2015

Just downloaded the Visual Studio 2015 Community edition. One of tutorial shows that a project can be created using the "File > New" menu option but the only menu options under File that I see are for the "New File" or "New Folder"

What am I missing? Are the projects/templates not available under the community edition or do I have to install templates?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

When you start a Visual Studio, the IDE itself will display a Start Up page if you are sure that you have installed it correctly.

You can create a new project with the menu options else the easiest is to use the options in this start up page from your left side of your IDE.

[image]